# How to determine to use trait to 'with' or class to 'inject'?

Tags: class, scala, traits

I'm puzzled to choose a `trait` or `class` when writing scala code.

At first, I have a controller which `with` several traits:

```
class MyController extends Controller 
                   with TransactionSupport 
                   with JsonConverterSupport 
                   with LoggerSupport
```

In these traits, I defined some methods and fields which can be used in `MyController` directly.

But my friend says: when you `extends` or `with` a trait, it should `be a` that trait.

Look at the `MyController`, it is a `Controller`, but it isn't a `TransactionSupport`, not a `JsonConverterSupport`, not a `LoggerSupport`, so it should not `with` them.

So the code becomes:

```
class MyController(tranSupport: TransactionSupport, 
                   jsonConverter: JsonConverterSupport, 
                   loggerSupport: LoggerSupport) extends Controller
```

But I don't feel good about this code, it just seems strange.

I see `trait`s used heavily in scala code, when should I use it or use classes to inject?

Answer (score 6):

I'll refer you to [Interfaces should be Adjectives](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InterfacesShouldBeAdjectives). Though some traits may play the part of a class (and, therefore, be nouns and respect the "is-a" relationship), when used as mixins they'll tend to play the part of interfaces.

As an "adjective", the trait will add a qualifying property to whatever they are extending. For example, they may be `Comparable` or `Serializable`.

It can be a bit hard to find an adjective to fit -- what adjective would you use for `LoggerSupport`? -- so don't feel overly constrained by that. Just be aware that it is completely wrong to thing of traits as necessarily an "is-a" relationship.

I would try to avoid using traits to replace "has-a" relationships, though.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that it doesn't have `to be` it. Mixing-in is a different concept than inheritance. Even though syntactically it is the same, it doesn't mean the same. Typical use case for mixing-in is logging just like you wrote. It doesn't mean that if your service class mixes-in a `Logging` trait that `it is` a logger. It's just a yet another way how to compose functionality into working objects.

Odersky proposes that if you are not sure and you can, use `trait`s because they are more flexible. You can change `trait` to `class` in the future if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime when I feel that mixing-in trait doesn't look good, I use module pattern like this:

```
trait JsonConverterModule {

    protected def jsonConverter: JsonConverter

    protected trait JsonConverter {
      def convert(in: Json): Json
    }
  }

class MyController extends Controller with JsonConverterModule {
   private doSmth = jsonConverter.convert(...)
}
```

MyController in this case looks more like a Controller, and all Json-related stuff is hidden from  MyController 'client'

Answer (score 0):

Your first example with traits is the "cake pattern" and your second example is "constructor injection". Both are perfectly valid ways to do dependency injection in Scala. The cake pattern is powerful, you can inject type members, the different traits can easily talk to each other (we don't have to create separate objects and pass them to each other object, often requiring setter injection rather than simple constructor injection), etc. However, the type has to be realized at compile-time, and a separate class must be realized for every combination of traits. Constructor injection lets you build your object at run-time and scales better for a large number of combinations.